# Get all records where sum of children (quantity) is less than parent (also quantity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to get all Products where the sum of the products sales quantity is less the the products quantity.

This is what I tried:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales

  scope :available, lambda { where(sales.sum(:quantity) < quantity)}
end
```

But this gives me `` undefined local variable or method `sales' for #<Class:0x007fd2f571ac58> ``
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sum` of a specific field in your table is obtained by grouping the rows you need in your SQL statement and then applying the aggregate function on it.

Your specific problem may be translated in ActiveRecord likewise :

```
Product.joins(:sales).
        group("sales.product_id").
        having("sum(sales.quantity) < sum(products.quantity)").
        select("products.*")
```

You must use `having` here because `where` does not apply on on the aggregate function (aka `sum`, `count`, `avg` etc)

Comment: This is what I needed, but I had to use "joins" instead of "join".